# Using possessive apostrophes after users' names

Tags: support, comments, display-names, comment-replies

[What's a word that means deflect blame?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/485330/what-s-a-word-that-means-deflect-blame)

In this post I posted a comment in response to another. In the post, I tagged someone's username, but in its possessive form. I put a space in between the username and the apostrophe, because I wasn't sure if the username tag would disappear if an apostrophe and an *s* was added.

I know this is a tiny problem, that can easily be avoided, but I'd like to know: Are there algorithms in place that keep the tag in place even though an apostrophe and an *s* is added?

Comment: Yes, it does work. For more information, check out the FAQ [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: I believe all you need is enough initial letters (with a minimum of 3, unless the name has less than that) for it to uniquely match one of of the commenters in a thread. Having said that, I suspect that if one person is "sam" and another is "samantha," you need to use `@sama` to identify the latter, while `@sam` would go to the former. I'm not certain what happens if both users (who actually have a numerical ID at the backend) use the same display name—something that's possible.